# Use css class to place react component in the layout

Tags: css, reactjs

I got the following components

```
|-- App
    |-- Components
        |-- WidgetMenu
        |-- Editor
```

I want to place `WidgetMenu` component in 3 locations in `App` as below.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "left center right"
  "bottom bottom bottom";
  
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.bottom {
  grid-area: bottom;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.center {
  grid-area: center;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container ">
  <div class="left">WidgetMenu Left</div>
  <div class="right">WidgetMenu Right</div>
  <div class="bottom">WidgetMenu Bottom</div>
  <div class="center">Editor</div>
</div>
```

To do that, I'm using css class as follows.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <WidgetMenu className="left" />
            <WidgetMenu className="right" />
            <WidgetMenu className="bottom" />
            <Editor className="center" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

But I can not pass a className because there is no such property requested by `WidgetMenu`. So how this should be done? What would be the proper way? Do I have to wrap every react component by `div`s and use className on them?

Comment: Why not pass `className` as `props` to the `WidgetMenu`? `<WidgetMenu classToApply={"left"} />`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Or he / she can just use the prop `className` :)

Comment: Layouting is done on `App` component by `App.css` style sheet. There is no real use of the class name inside `WidgetMenu`. That's why I want to know if there is any other way.

Comment: You can't use the `className` on a component because it has no DOM, so you have a DOM element to apply the class on. But you can split the code. The parent (App) will contains the styles which relevant to it and in Widget.css put the styles which relevant to the widgets..

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava @MoshFeu 
even if i define a prop called `className` react just take it as a regular prop value.
`<WidgetMenu className="left" />`

Comment: Yes so you have to do something with this prop value inside the code of your `WidgetMenu` component.

Comment: @MoshFeu Both `App` and `WidgetMenu` has separate `css` relevant to them.  Placing the widget in the right location is a responsibility of  `App` component.

Comment: I can accept that. React doesn't "know" what to do with the `className` prop because it has no element to "wire" the `class` attribute on. So, as I said, you have to wrap the children of `WidgetMenu` with a DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this in your parent component,

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <WidgetMenu className="left" />
            <WidgetMenu className="right" />
            <WidgetMenu className="bottom" />
            <Editor className="center" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the child component (WidgetMenu & Editor components), you have to apply it this way:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.className}>WidgetMenu {this.props.className}</div>
    );
}
```